# How can I stop Generate Customization Script from deleting/ignoring my added ASPX code?

Tags: acumatica

It seems that sometimes, not always, when I add code to an ASPX page via Customization Project -> Screens ->  -> Actions -> Edit ASPX and click Generate Customization Scripts, it deletes what I added. What I'm adding doesn't contain any errors as I write it in VS and then copy and paste it into the editor. This sometimes work and sometimes does not. When it does not work, I cannot make changes no matter what I do.

Is there a way to prevent Generate Customization Scripts from deleting the code I add?

Is there a way to edit and see changes to ASPX files after publishing via Visual Studio instead of using the browser editor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you testing your changes directly in the aspx page that you are customization to an existing screen?

I assume this is the case and I have found when I go and look at the generate script changes to the page it already includes my changes because I added them to the page and this process simply loads the same contents. Because its already there my guess is this is why the "changes" are ignored.

Here is what I do and maybe it will help you:

1. Save the standard aspx screen (before changes) somewhere to revert back later.
2. Make/test your changes to the aspx page
3. Save the modified aspx screen changes somewhere
4. Restore the original aspx screen (saved from step 1)
5. Go to your customization and paste in your changes to the screen > edit aspx
6. Click Generate Customization Script

Now your changes should be in place and saved.

This doesn't apply if you are writing your own aspx as this is included as a file in your customization project. This is in reference to modifying an existing aspx file from Acumatica or another customization.

Comment: Both answers work, I wish I could approve them both!

Comment: Glad it worked. It would be best to pick the one that worked best for you and mark it as the answer so the question is not left "unanswered"

Comment: Typically I copy and paste entire ASPX pages from VS to the broswer editor, but in this instance it keeps removing one line of code. The line it removes is an additional PXTreeDataMember in the DataTrees cluster. Any suggestions on why it keeps removing this specific line?

Comment: I have found that not everything you paste in or can use in an ASPX is allowed to be used in a customization project. So there are some limitations to what you can customize to an existing page. Why your specific question on PXTreeDataMember doesn't work i am not sure. Maybe post as another question to get better traction on the issue. If no bites then maybe a support case with Acumatica

Comment: Thanks Brendan, I started a case with Acumatica on this issue.

Answer (score 3):

The Generate Customization Scripts button does a very strict validation which will sometime remove valid markup. There isn't much you can do about this.

If you are modifying custom screens, you can modify the .aspx file directly from the **{WebsitePath}\CstPublished** and **{WebsitePath}\Pages** folders.

Modifications done to files in CstPublished will be reflected instantly after refreshing the web page.

Modifications done to files from the Pages folder will updated the customization project, as you should get a conflict pop-up in the Project Editor screen.

My preferred workflow is to modify CstPublished files, test in the screen and if it works, I copy paste my change to the Pages folder.

Comment: Both answers work, I wish I could approve them both!

Comment: Will modifying a standard Acumatica page under files write the changes to the screen changes in the project xml? (not as a file change)

Comment: Unfortunately modification done in CSTPublished or Pages folders on standard screen can't be included in a customization project. It is still useful for quick tests.

Comment: ok yes i agree. I was going to say that is a nice hidden feature i have not seen yet :) thanks for confirming